Vue3 conditional class overwrites other classes
I work on a Vue3/Leaflet project. I set a conditional class in the map container:
<template>
  <div id="map" :class="{ 'zoom-close': zoomLevel >= 7 }"></div>
</template>

This seemed to work at first glance -- but outside of Vue, Leaflet itself sets a bunch of classes in the map container. When the condition is false, Vue would not only remove my class zoom-close but also all these other classes.
Is there a way to tell Vue3: "Set this one class conditionally and leave all the others alone"?

I don't think it's possible: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5677

You can always use a dedicated wrapper: <div :class="{ zoom-close: zoomLevel >=7 }"><div id="map"></div></div>. Or you could use vue-leaflet.

My workaround was to use a data- attribute instead of the class.
Thanks for the issue link, @Sjoertjuh -- it's seven years old but it seems this behavior hasn't changed.
